# What is overriding Windows proxy settings (inserting "vsts-proxy-installed-indicator") and how do I turn it off?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a number of machines, all of which have Visual Studio installed, where something (presumably visual studio) is overriding the proxy settings: setting up localhost and some random port for both HTTP and HTTPS. In the "Do not use proxy server" box, it puts `<vsts-proxy-installed-indicator>` which is presumably a tag so it know it's done it.

[image: VSTS proxy settings]

This occasionally prevents browsers from working on my desktop, and more recently, changed it on our build server which caused the code signing step (which connects to an external timestamp server) to fail all day until I finally found this proxy issue.

What is changing these settings? Why is it changing them? How do I turn it off?

---

Note, there is a serverfault question about this as well: [What is inserting “vsts-proxy-installed-indicator”?](https://serverfault.com/questions/253231/what-is-inserting-vsts-proxy-installed-indicator) but since this is a Visual Studio-specific question, I thought it might be better to ask here.

Comment: This is happening for me too. What visual studio extensions do you have installed, I wonder if it's something to do with them?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This happens because you've enabled "**ASP.NET Client Proxy for IntelliTrace and Test Impact**" in the Test Settings.

To disable - **VS2010**: Open the menu `Test` > `Edit Test Settings` > (select the current active test settings), select `Data and Diagnostics` and disable the mentioned setting.

To disable - **VS2013**: Double click on the enabled* `.testsettings`-file in the solutions explorer, select `Data and Diagnostics` and disable the mentioned setting.

*) You'll find which one is enabled (if any) under `TEST`> `Test settings`

Comment: I'd +1 again if I could because you were awesome enough to come back and update this again for VS2013 :)

Comment: I have not got a .testsettings file, how do I stop vs2013 form making these proxy changes?

Comment: I am in VS 2013 as well.  The settings in the file (which I *THINK* are what I need do not have this setting.)  The solution contains almost 20 projects, including 5 Test projects (and growing).  I never had this problem until a get from TFS yesterday.  I am not finding a way to shut this down!

Answer (score 1):

Keep `<vsts-proxy-installed-indicator>` in the exception list along with the other proxy and exception settings. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like running mstests (e.g., from the "Test List Editor" tab triggers this! Can someone reproduce?

Comment: It would be better if you put related questions/clarifications as comments rather than as answers.

Comment: Seems to be the case for me, too.

Comment: Excellent. I think? Now why is this happening and what can we do about it? There is an MS forum post, but they blame 'third party' software. I don't buy it.

Comment: This happens in VB.NET, does this also happen in C#?

Comment: Happens to me too in VS2010 C# unit test projects. Also when the test finishes it sometimes forgets to reset the proxy settings. Brilliant!