# Coded UI - How to prevent Debug mode from enabling LAN proxy server settings and clearing previous proxy settings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, coded-ui-tests, proxy-server

When running a web test in debug mode using VS2012(Premium)/Coded UI, every time I use debug WITH a breakpoint in the code, the Internet Options->Connections->LAN Settings->"Use a proxy server for your LAN(These settings will not apply to dial-up or VPN connections)." checkbox becomes enabled. If I don't have any breakpoints in the code, it executes fine and does not change any internet option settings.

I've tried running it with "Automatically detect settings" both enabled and disabled, with adding an exception to "*" in the proxy server settings advanced menu, with adding my specific servers as exceptions in the proxy server settings advanced menu.  Everything I do is overridden and once the test hits the breakpoint, all changes to the proxy settings are overridden and "Use a proxy server for your LAN..." is still checked.

How do I prevent VS12/CodedUI from changing these proxy settings?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221351/what-is-overriding-windows-proxy-settings-inserting-vsts-proxy-installed-indic

Comment: Thanks Aetos! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221351/what-is-overriding-windows-proxy-settings-inserting-vsts-proxy-installed-indic

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer right here on StackOverflow.com!

Thank Ja' for StackOverflow.com

See:

**What is overriding Windows proxy settings (inserting “vsts-proxy-installed-indicator”) and how do I turn it off?**

[What is overriding Windows proxy settings (inserting "vsts-proxy-installed-indicator") and how do I turn it off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221351/what-is-overriding-windows-proxy-settings-inserting-vsts-proxy-installed-indic)