# difference between launch site from iis and iis express

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

So i have tiny asp.net application containing the only page.
It is code from Page_Load method (it is only code in code-behind):

```
string url = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/access_token?client_id=123&client_secret=123&code=123&redirect_uri=mysite.com";
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
/* 
if i comment this line 
i get exception an exception with following message
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required
*/
webRequest.Proxy = null; 
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse()) // 
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        TokenBox.Text = str;
    }
}
```

So what is my problem? This application is deployed in iis 7.5. When i ise it as iis site i get an exception WebException with message "Unable to connect to the remote server". But if i press F5 button in Visual Studio and debug my web application with IIS Express this code works fine. 
What is the reason of this weird behavior? How can i fix it and make my app to work properly from IIS site?

Comment: Do you use the same browser for testing the IIS website and debugging?

Comment: Check this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221351/what-is-overriding-windows-proxy-settings-inserting-vsts-proxy-installed-indic

Comment: I tried  both ways and result was the same

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/04/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis/

To make a request out, .NET/Windows requires proper networking settings (such as proxy, authentication and so on), which might be OK for your account to run the code in VS. However, IIS obviously won't guarantee the code to work, because you did not yet set the application pool identity with the same networking settings.